# Yii2: How to render Pjax content outside of Gridview, triggered with Gridview button

Tags: button, gridview, yii2, pjax

### Issue

For those with this issue, I'll save you some headache.

In summary: It is critical that the Pjax linkSelector must point to an **< a >** anchor element or you will receive an uncaught jquery error.

[image: Pjax Button vs Link Tag]

The issue I was having was updating content outside of the Gridview Widget using Pjax. I added a custom button using Html::button, but the pjax was failing for unknown reason.

When testing pjax on the gridview widget using the native buttons using  'class'=>'yii\grid\ActionColumn', the pjax would refresh just fine which caused me some confusion. What I didn't realize is that the pjax linkSelector only works on **< a >** elements, the linkSelector will not work on **< button >** element generated when using Html::button(...); .

> **Recieved this error:** Uncaught $.fn.pjax or $.pjax.click requires an anchor element.

### View

> **File Location:** *app/views/default/pjax-example.php*

#### [Code for Pjax]

```
<?php Pjax::begin([
    'id'=>'p0',
    'timeout' => false,
    //Selector must target the <a> anchor.      
    'linkSelector'=>'.action-select', 
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

#### [Code for Gridview Widget]

```
$data = [
    ['step_id' => 1, 'step_name' => 'Step A'],
    ['step_id' => 2, 'step_name' => 'Step B'],
    ['step_id' => 3, 'step_name' => 'Step C'],
];
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $data,
    'sort' => [
       'attributes' => ['id', 'name'],
    ],
]);
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'tableOptions' => [
        'class' => 'table',
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'step_id',
        'step_name',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
            'label' => 'Button-1',
            'format'=> 'raw',
            'value' => function ($url, $data) {
                return Html::a(
                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span>',
                    Url::to(['default/select', 'id'=>$data['step_id']]),
                    [
                        'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs action-select',
                        'data-pjax'=> 'p0', // We must specify the pjax ID.
                    ]
                );
            },
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{select}',
            'header' => 'Button-2',
            'buttons' => [
              'select' => function ($url, $data) {
                return Html::Button(
                  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>',
                  ['value' => Url::to(['default/select', $data['step_id']]),
                    'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs action-select',
                    'data-pjax'=> 'p0',
                ]);
              },
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

### Controller

> **File Location:** *app/controllers/defaultController.php*

```
public function actionSelect()
{
    $random_val = 'Rand_01: ' . rand(10,100);
    return $random_val;
}

public function actionPjaxExample()
{
    $random_val = 'Rand_02: ' . rand(10,100);
    return $this->render('pjax-example', [
        'random_val' => $random_val
    ]);
}
```

Comment: you can't use the button without into form. It is better that you use the link

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code without a link selector. And also without `data-pjax=0`

views/tranlate/index.php

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'translate-grid', 'timeout' => false, 'enablePushState' => true]) ?>
# here you form
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action'=> Url::current(),'id'=>'edit-form']) ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'word')->textInput() ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
           'id' => 'data-grid',
           'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
           'columns'      => [
              [
                'attribute' => 'title',
                'format'    => 'raw',
                'value'     => function ($model) {
                    return Html::a($name, [                                                                    
                        'id' => $model->id
                    ]);
                 },
              ],
           ]
     ]) ?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

controllers/TranalteController.php

```
public function actionIndex($id = false)
{
    $searchModel = new TranslateSearch();
    $model       = $id ? $this->findModel($id) : new Translate();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->getReferrer());
        }
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        'model'        => $model,
        'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->get()),
    ]);
}
```